# Find and replace after n matches and before m matches with AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

Currently I'm using AWK to find and replace a portion of the first three occurrences of a string. The string is formatted as such, and there are many of these strings in the file:

`func(tempID="39849235",count='12');`

Using [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/394282/sed-perform-only-first-nth-matched-replacement), I was able to find a method of using AWK to find and replace the first three instances of the string. I changed it to what I needed it to do, and a snippet of my script is below:

```
id=12349876
awk 'BEGIN {matches=0}
     matches < 3 && /.*tempID.*/ { sub(/tempID=.[0-9]+./,"tempID='"$id"'"); matches++ }
     { print $0 }' filName.py >filName.py.changed
```

The goal of the above code is to match on any line containing tempID and replace the number that is assigned to tempID with a value held in a variable named `$id`. The find and replace works well, but now I want to replace instances 4-9 with a different number. I tried the following method, but it still only replaced the first 5 instances of tempID:

```
id2=39843237
awk 'BEGIN {matches=4}
     matches < 9 && /.*tempID.*/ { sub(/tempID=.[0-9]+./,"tempID='"$id2"'"); matches++ }
     { print $0 }' filName.py >filName.py.changed
```

Is there another way to implement this so that that range of values is replaced? It doesn't have to be with AWK, it can be with sed or any other Linux utility.

**Edit:** Below is an example of what the lines should look like before and after:

*Before:*

```
func2(blah)
func3(blah)
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');

func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
```

*After:*

```
func2(blah)
func3(blah)
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="83747432",count='12');
func(tempID="39843237",count='12');

func(tempID="39843237",count='12');
func(tempID="39843237",count='12');
```

Notice how the lines after the third line are changed, but only the third line that matches the pattern `.*tempID.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making up my own sample input file with numbers by the lines that match your target function call just to highlight that similar but not identical lines are ignored:

```
$ cat file
1 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
2 here is one func(tempID="39849235",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
3 and another:           func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
4 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
5 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
6 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
7 here is one func(tempID="39849235",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
8 and another:           func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
9 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
10 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
```

and using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/(.*\<func\(tempID=")39849235(",count='12'\);.*)/,a) {
    ++cnt
    if ( (cnt >= beg) && (cnt <= end) ) {
        $0 = a[1] id a[2]
    }
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ id=12349876
$ awk -v id="$id" -v beg=1 -v end=3 -f tst.awk file
1 func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
2 here is one func(tempID="12349876",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
3 and another:           func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
4 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
5 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
6 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
7 here is one func(tempID="39849235",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
8 and another:           func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
9 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
10 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
```

.

```
$ id=12349876
$ awk -v id="$id" -v beg=4 -v end=9 -f tst.awk file
1 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
2 here is one func(tempID="39849235",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
3 and another:           func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
4 func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
5 func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
6 func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
boofunc(tempID="39849235",count='12');
7 here is one func(tempID="12349876",count='12'); right there
func(tempID="99999999",count='12');
func(tempID="39849235",count='123');
8 and another:           func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
9 func(tempID="12349876",count='12');
10 func(tempID="39849235",count='12');
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to what I wanted, but the count values and IDs won't always be the same, so it's not exactly what I was looking for. That was my fault for not being clear enough though, so I'll upvote your answer but have the person who answered my question on a different forum answer here and accept their answer, since that solution worked for me and was the one I ended up going with. Thank you for taking the time to answer nonetheless!

Comment: Can't you see that the count values and id are passed as arguments to the program so you can just change them to whatever you want every time you call it? What did you think `-v id="$id" -v beg=4 -v end=9` meant?

Comment: I looked at [the answer you accepted on the other forum](https://superuser.com/a/1380555) btw and it has some issues including it: 1) will falsely match lines other than your target line, 2) duplicates the text "tempID" in **4 different locations**, 3) has basic regexp issues, e.g. what do you think `/.*tempID.*/` will match that just `/tempID/` won't, 4) increments matches AFTER the test that uses its value and so forces the numbers being compared to be other than the numbers you want, 5) $0 is what's printed by default so you can just say `print`, 6) the whole BEGIN section is redundant.

Comment: Of course I can see that the count and id values are passed as arguments, that's not my point. My point was that the count and tempID values are static in your AWK code and are specified as 39849235 and count='12' respectively, which I didn't want because my Python function isn't going to have the same tempID and count values passed as parameters each time. As I said though, it was my mistake in not clarifying that they would be different. Please change your answer to account for variable tempID and count values and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Your question said the string to match was `func(tempID="39849235",count='12');`. My answer answered your question, I've no idea what else you might have meant other than what you wrote - accept this answer (or not, doesn't matter either way to me) and write a new question if your question doesn't capture your real requirements.